# $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz$ where $C$ is the circle $\left|z \right|=3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz$$ where $C$ is the circle $\left|z \right|=3$.

So we know that $-2$ is contained in the interior of the circle and that $f(z)=e^z$ is entire analytic. Thus by Cauchy integral formula,

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz = f(-2)=e^{-2}.$$ Answer says it's $e^2$, but I think it's wrong since we can write $\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}=\frac{e^z}{-2-(-2)}$, so $z_0=-2$. Is my answer correct or am I missing something?

Comment: $z-z_0=z-2\implies z_0=2$. Moreover, the function $e^z/(z-2)$ is perfectly well-behaved near $z=-2$ (it equals $e^{-2}/(-4)$) and thus has no pole there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do note that CIT says, with the conditions you already wrote in your question, that

$$f(a)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$

For you to get $\;e^{-2}\;$ it'd have to be

$$\oint_c\frac{e^z}{z+2}dz\;\;,\;\;\;\text{since}\;\;\;z+2=z-(-2)$$